# Are there any Open-Source bricks projects for robotics?

Tags: robotic, open-source

I mean some bricks like Lego/Meccano with a community like Instructables site, those share their models and robots with others. Also the 3D models of bricks(in solidworks format for example) are free to use or the parts are available to buy at the market!

Comment: I know of 3 books that might help you:

Comment: 1. [link] http://www.allitebooks.com/lego-mindstorms-ev3-2nd-edition/                      2. [link] http://www.allitebooks.com/beginning-robotics-programming-in-java-with-lego-mindstorms/                                                                                                 3. [link]http://www.allitebooks.com/the-lego-mindstorms-ev3-idea-book/

Comment: I think using Rebrickable would suit you.